# Splash Screen for Python GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, splash-screen

so I am new to python and have been trying to create a python app for saving .exe files to then open up whenever you "run" the app. I have managed to do this, after some youtube tutorials and some notes on here too; however, I wanted to add a splash screen to my application, and I'm trying to follow along with some examples, but so far the splash screen isn't displaying. As far as I can tell, the code should be working and the screen itself should display, not that it would be working 100%, but it should just display. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong and could use some help in figuring out what to do next; below is my code prior to trying to implement a splash screen:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Start My Apps")
apps = []

if os.path.isfile('save.txt'):
    with open('save.txt', 'r') as f:
        tempApps = f.read()
        tempApps = tempApps.split(',')
        apps = [x for x in tempApps if x.strip()]

def addApp():
    for widget in frame1.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title="Select File", filetypes = (("executables","*.exe"),("all files" , "*")))

    apps.append(filename)
    print(filename)
    for app in apps:
        label1 = tk.Label(frame1, text = app, bg="gray")
        label1.pack()

def runApps():
    for app in apps:
            os.startfile(app)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=700, width=700, bg="#263D42")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

frame1 = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
frame1.place(relwidth = 0.8, relheight = 0.8, relx = 0.1, rely = 0.1)

frame2 = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
frame2.place(relwidth = 0.8, relheight = 0.05, relx = 0.1, rely = .02)

label2 = tk.Label(frame2, text = "Welcome to: Start My Apps!", font='times 20 bold',bg="white")
label2.pack()

openFile = tk.Button(root, text = "Open File", padx = 10, pady = 5, fg="white", bg="#263D42", command = addApp)
openFile.pack()

runApps = tk.Button(root, text = "Run Apps", padx = 10, pady = 5, fg="white", bg="#263D42", command = runApps)
runApps.pack()

for app in apps:
    label1 = tk.Label(frame1, text = app)
    label1.pack()

root.mainloop()

with open('save.txt', 'w') as f:
    for app in apps:
        f.write(app + ',')
```

The second portion of the code is when I tried to implment the splash screen:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import os


splash_root = Tk()
splash_root.title("Welcome to: Start My Apps!")
splash_root.geometry("700x700")

splash_label = Label(splash_root, text = "Welcome to: Start My Apps!", font='times 20 bold',bg="white")
splash_label.pack(pady=20)

def main_window():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Start My Apps")

apps = []

if os.path.isfile('save.txt'):
    with open('save.txt', 'r') as f:
        tempApps = f.read()
        tempApps = tempApps.split(',')
        apps = [x for x in tempApps if x.strip()]

def addApp():
    for widget in frame1.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title="Select File", filetypes = (("executables","*.exe"),("all files" , "*")))

    apps.append(filename)
    print(filename)
    for app in apps:
        label1 = tk.Label(frame1, text = app, bg="gray")
        label1.pack()

def runApps():
    for app in apps:
            os.startfile(app)

canvas = tk.Canvas(height=700, width=700, bg="#263D42")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

frame1 = tk.Frame(bg="white")
frame1.place(relwidth = 0.8, relheight = 0.8, relx = 0.1, rely = 0.1)

frame2 = tk.Frame(bg="white")
frame2.place(relwidth = 0.8, relheight = 0.05, relx = 0.1, rely = .02)

label2 = tk.Label(frame2, text = "Welcome to: Start My Apps!", font='times 20 bold',bg="white")
label2.pack()

openFile = tk.Button(text = "Open File", padx = 10, pady = 5, fg="white", bg="#263D42", command = addApp)
openFile.pack()

runApps = tk.Button(text = "Run Apps", padx = 10, pady = 5, fg="white", bg="#263D42", command = runApps)
runApps.pack()

for app in apps:
    label1 = tk.Label(frame1, text = app)
    label1.pack()

mainloop()

with open('save.txt', 'w') as f:
    for app in apps:
        f.write(app + ',')
```

like I said, I'm new to this coding style so if there is anything else you see that is wrong, or just doesn't make sense, please let me know!

Comment: I cant see anywhere that you called `splash_root.mainloop()` as this is a `Tk()` i think its necessary to say a `mainloop()` for the window to appear

Comment: @CoolCloud would I place after: splash_root = Tk() or before?

Comment: You could even  use a module called `tksplash` check the docs on pypi.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Tk()` window doesnt show up unless you put it inside a `mainloop()`, so it should be something like:

```
splash_root = Tk()
splash_root.title("Welcome to: Start My Apps!")
splash_root.geometry("700x700")

splash_label = Label(
    splash_root, text="Welcome to: Start My Apps!", font='times 20 bold', bg="white")
splash_label.pack(pady=20)

splash_root.after(5000,splash_root.destroy) #after(ms,func)
splash_root.mainloop()
```

I used `splash_root.after()` because since its a splash screen, it has to be destroyed automatically, rather than manually. This will close the splash screen after 5 seconds or 5000 ms.

This might also explain why `Toplevel()` windows dont need a `mainloop()` as they use the `mainloop()` of the main window.

Comment: I appreciate the help, it's actually working now; the tutorial that I was attempting to use, was showing me I had to do more than what you posted! I wanted to ask something else of you, if I can; My program allows for the user to select .exe files in their file directory that will then be opened up once the program is run. That part works fine, but I am unsure of how to create a way to allow the user to delete a .exe file that they dont want to use anymore.

Comment: @Zethos Use `os.remove()`, take a look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-remove-method/)